# What is cosmic ray albedo neutron decay (CRAND)?

Tags: neutrons, cosmic-rays

I need a small description of what is [cosmic ray albedo neutron decay](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=cosmic+ray+albedo+neutron+decay) (CRAND), where it comes from and what effects they have?

Comment: For anyone that is intrested in that subject area, i found that link which may be helpfull : https://www.nature.com/articles/nature24642

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard the specific acronym CRAND.

However, cosmic rays which reach Earth's ground level lose energy by, among other processes, [spallation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spallation) on the heavy nuclei in the soil and rock.  Some of these spallation neutrons will leak back out of the surface of the ground, having partially thermalized$^1$.
These neutrons basically form a very tenuous part of Earth's atmosphere, with a scale height somewhat higher than the nitrogen/oxygen/ozone parts of the atmosphere, because the neturons' temperatures are comparable to the other gas species, but the neutrons are less massive.
I think an astronomer might consider these "[albedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albedo) neutrons from cosmic rays" (your CRAN).

A [thermal neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_temperature#Thermal) at the ground, with average speed $v\sim 2\rm\,km/s$, can certainly reach the ionosphere/exosphere within its 1000 second half-life.  The fraction that decay above the atmosphere will contribute to the population of electrons and protons trapped there.

My dumb Google search also finds [solar proton albedo neutron decay](https://doi.org/10.1029/JZ071i005p01293), which sounds like the same effect but triggered by the solar wind rather than by cosmic rays.
That would be more important on a planet without an atmosphere or magnetosphere to modulate the solar wind protons.

My slightly less dumb search finds [this 2017 *Nature* paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature24642)
that says I mostly guessed right, but that my involvement of the ground rather than the upper atmosphere was some terrestrial chauvinism on my part.

---

$^1$ One of the early papers describing these neutrons has a great comparison between the detectable neutron flux in St. Petersburg in a boat in the harbor (where the spallation neutrons from the seabed are mostly captured in the seawater), over bare ground (poorly thermalized), and over a meter of snow (well-thermalized). All I'm finding today are balloon flights:
[Flerov et al., JETP **9**, 511 (1959)](http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/e/index/e/9/3/p511?a=list); [Kopff, Phys. Rev. **59**, 949 (1941)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.59.949).

Comment: *::chuckles::* I nominate the use of *"very tenuous"* here for understatement of the year.

Comment: @dmckee I'd like to have a number in my head for the cosmic ray neutron number density, to compare to e.g. the [metal ion atmosphere of Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mercury), but I couldn't do it in fifteen minutes. That seems too homeworky for a followup question, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the resources that come to my mind immediately are for fairly deep neutrino detectors, so they don't give you the near-surface production rates or the fraction that wander back to emerge above ground. But I think you can get some sense of the scale from the lack of a line-item for this process in background radiation source charts.